# How can i get dynamic values(lectureid) while click 'Add' button in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My scenario,

While click "Add" button, Getting `"lectureid"` from the database for my application.

In the above scenario, How can I get `'lecture id'`(dynamic) value in `JMeter3.0` and refer the snapshot?

[image]

Kindly give me the solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Regular Expression Extractor` configuration should be like:

```
Reference name: Courselectureid (Could be anything)
Regular Expression: "courselectureid":(\d+)
Template: $1$
Match No.(0 For Random): 1
```

For Regex test see here: https://regex101.com/r/MdHaYq/1

Here, the total number of match found will be 4, but you need to extract only one of the values `1429`. That's why `Match No.(0 For Random): 1` is used. You could use the value `0`, in that case, it will pick a match randomly. In you case, it will not have any impact as all the matches are returning the same value `1429`.